# How to look for words in a CLOB

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have been at this process for a wile and have used `INSTR()` and have never had any problem with it until
now. `a.review` is a CLOB and `INSTR()` has worked in a simple SELECT statement.

```
DECLARE
lv_hotel NUMBER;
seed_cnt NUMBER;
lv_cat NUMBER;
lv_pol NUMBER;
f NUMBER;
BEGIN
FOR f IN 1..4176
LOOP
SELECT a.IDHotel ,DBMS_LOB.INSTR(a.review, b.seed_words), b.CATEGORYID, SUM(b.Polarity) 
                    INTO lv_hotel, seed_cnt, lv_cat, lv_pol
                      FROM review a, SEEDWORDS b
                      GROUP BY a.IDHOTEL, b.CategoryID, DBMS_LOB.INSTR(a.review, b.seed_words), a.review, b.seed_words;
                    FOR lv_cat IN 1..4
                    LOOP
                    INSERT INTO RATINGS (RATING)
                    VALUES(lv_pol);
                    END LOOP;
                    END LOOP;                   
                END;
```

When I run the above code I get the errors as seen below:

```
 Error report -
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got CLOB
ORA-06512: at line 11
00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Is there away around this? Should I use a REGEX function?

Answer (score 0):

[`DBMS_LOB.INSTR`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_lob.htm#i998546)

> INSTR Functions
>
> This function returns the matching position of the nth
>   occurrence of the pattern in the LOB, starting from the offset you
>   specify.

Update:

I never realized you're doing `group by a.review`. You cannot use CLOB column in a group by clause. No way around that unless you cast it to varchar2. That logic will need to be reconsidered.

Comment: I Changed INSTR(a.review, b.seed_words) to DBMS_LOB.INSTR(a.review, b.seed_words) and still revived the same error. Is there something that I may have missed?

Comment: what is the data type of b.seed_words?

Comment: and just to make sure - you changed it in `group by` as well, right? :)

Comment: I have edited the code in the post to what I tried. Yes i changed it in the group by

Comment: can you update error message as well? (the line# probably changed). and what about `b.seed_words` data type?

Comment: oh. never mind, I just realized. you're having `a.review` in `group by`. you cannot group by clob columns. the query logic will need to be changed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202998/discussion-between-nathanc-and-kirill-leontev).